# How to install Addin Excel made with Angular in Excel

Tags: angular, office-js, excel-addins, office-js-helpers

### Situation :

I'm a newbie in add-in excel, so this could be a stupid question.

I made an Excel add-in(Side load) test project by using Angular. I followed the [Microsoft tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/excel-quickstart-angular)

My test project works fine in local environment, but I want to know how can I install my add-in in the Excel of my user.

### What I want:

I read the [publish documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/publish/publish) of Microsoft, but it's not I want.

I want to know if it's possible to generate a package with my excel add-in project and import to excel directly ?

This is my [test project excel add-in using Angular](https://github.com/Yiao/PocExcel) and I made a [Back Service](https://github.com/Yiao/PocExcelBackService) for it too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Office add-ins cannot be distributed as a package in the way that you want. They have to be published in one of the ways described in the publish documentation that you linked to.